# jqTransform and ASP.NET does work, why?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I get this message while pressing on ASP:Button in IE 8 in Compatibility Mode while my form has jqTransform applied to it.

"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButtonRegister="register..."). "

Without it works fine, if i don't override Compatibility Mode with

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

i have half of my controls ugly with jqTransform

any help ? Why is 'span' passed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly jqTransform just adds css classes to controls, however IE in compatibility mode recreates all sorts of bugs and things from previous broser versions.  jqTransform is probably doing something nasty to try an work around CSS compatibility problems, e.g. it is injecting a span that overlays the control to try and reqcreate the effect normally acheived by just adding a CSS class to the control.

Comment: removed jqTransform from my project, did html controllers design by my own using simple JS and CSS. At least now i have control over what passed where ...
Thanks anyways...